# Why I can not place (for in) loop at program

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to program a simple app for picture displaying. I'd like to initialize array when app started  But I do not know where to  place the code. Code itself is without error but I can't execute it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var pictureNameArray = [String]()
    for i in 0...4 {
        pictureNameArray.append("imaage\(i)")
    }
    //["image0", "image1", "image2", "image3","image4"]
// I want to make array with this item

    @State private var pictureNameArrayIndex1 = 0
    @State private var pictureNameArrayIndex2 = 1



    func changePicture() {
           repeat {
            pictureNameArrayIndex1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 4)
            
            pictureNameArrayIndex2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 4)
            
            print(pictureNameArrayIndex1, pictureNameArrayIndex2)}
        while pictureNameArrayIndex1 == pictureNameArrayIndex2 
    }
    

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Label("Grand Son", systemImage:  "sun.and.horizon.circle").font(.title)
            Image(pictureNameArray[pictureNameArrayIndex1])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            Image(pictureNameArray[pictureNameArrayIndex2])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)    
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            

            
            Button(action: changePicture) {
                Label("Push Here", systemImage: "arrow.up").font(.title)
            }
            
                        
            }
                
                
            }
            
        
    
}
```

Comment: `var pictureNameArray = (0...4).map { "imaage\($0)" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we initialise the array as suggested by Leo Dabus in the comments and then simplify the code by only working with the array property and use the `shuffle()` to reorder the array each time the button is pressed we end up with much less code. And by using a `ForEach` when displaying the images we avoid having to use indices at all in our view code which makes the code cleaner and safer.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var pictureNameArray = (0...4).map { "image\($0)"}

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Label("Grand Son", systemImage:  "sun.and.horizon.circle").font(.title)
            ForEach(pictureNameArray.prefix(2), id: \.self) { image in
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            }

            Button { pictureNameArray.shuffle() } label: {
                Label("Push Here", systemImage: "arrow.up").font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you access your array indexes directly, your array needs to be filled before your view exists. You can initialize your array with `map` like:

```
var pictureNameArray = (0...4).map { "image\($0)" }
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var pictureNameArray = (0...4).map { "image\($0)" }
    @State private var pictureNameArrayIndex1 = 0
    @State private var pictureNameArrayIndex2 = 1
    
    func changePicture() {
        guard pictureNameArray.count > 0 else { return }
        repeat {
            pictureNameArrayIndex1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... pictureNameArray.count - 1)
            pictureNameArrayIndex2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... pictureNameArray.count - 1)
            print(pictureNameArrayIndex1, pictureNameArrayIndex2)}
        while pictureNameArrayIndex1 == pictureNameArrayIndex2
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Label("Grand Son", systemImage: "sun.and.horizon")
                .font(.title)
            Image(pictureNameArray[pictureNameArrayIndex1])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            Image(pictureNameArray[pictureNameArrayIndex2])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            Button(action: changePicture) {
                Label("Push Here", systemImage: "arrow.up").font(.title)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I put some additional safety in `changePicture` in case you decide to change the size of your array.

——
Update:
While this fixes the code and works, [Joakim Danielson‘s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77120626/16157878) is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have placed that code at the top level of the struct where no code will be executed (and indeed it isn’t valid).

For this you should probably put it in the init of the struct…

```
struct ContentView {
  init() {
    // set picture array here
  }
}
```

Comment: This will cause a crash on launch in the `Image` where the array is accessed out of range.

Comment: @soundflix which part of my code has an out of bounds error?! `pictureArray = (0…4).map { … }`. I think this comment might be on the wrong answer?